# Android - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I looked at other posts with this problem, but they seem to have some sort of connection to an `editText` field or an off by one error. In my case, none of the solutions from other posts seem to help. Here is my code:

```
public void push(int w, int h) {
    int[][] temp_arr = new int[arr.length+1][2];
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        temp_arr[i][0] = arr[i][0];
        temp_arr[i][1] = arr[i][1];
    }
    temp_arr[arr.length][0] = w; // happens here
    temp_arr[arr.length][1] = h;
    arr = temp_arr;
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Process: <package name>, PID: 16749
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=76; index=76
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you sure it happens here? is there any threading going on that would modify `arr`?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different `Thread`s calling `push` at the same time.

When the first one completes the execution of `push`, it replaces `arr` with `temp_arr`,  which is longer by 1.

When the second reaches `temp_arr[arr.length][0]`, there is an index error because the size of `arr` is not the same as when `temp_arr` was initialized.

To prevent this, you can either use an `ExecutorService` to run several `Runnable`s on the same `Thread`, serially : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29

or you can add a `synchronized` block :

```
public synchronized void push(int w, int h) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some threads are going on.

Solution: You have to ensure that some action must be **synchronized**

```
public synchronized void push(int w, int h) {
    int[][] temp_arr = new int[arr.length+1][2];
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        temp_arr[i][0] = arr[i][0];
        temp_arr[i][1] = arr[i][1];
    }
    temp_arr[arr.length][0] = w; // happens here
    temp_arr[arr.length][1] = h;
    arr = temp_arr;
}
```

And maybe you have another function that "**pop**" data from "**arr**". If you have this function, please add "**synchronized**" also.

```
public synchronized int pop(int w, int h) {
    //
}
```

Or another way:

```
public void push(int w, int h) {
    synchronized(arr) {
        int[][] temp_arr = new int[arr.length+1][2];
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            temp_arr[i][0] = arr[i][0];
            temp_arr[i][1] = arr[i][1];
        }
        temp_arr[arr.length][0] = w; // happens here
        temp_arr[arr.length][1] = h;
        arr = temp_arr;
    }
}
```

And please ensure that the "**pop**" function, you must **synchronize** "**arr**" also.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm here is the example about "synchronized"